# How do i rerun part of a code that uses an array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a code that takes a users input and prints their schedule, but I'm running into a problem with my do-while loop.

My program will not rerun. I'm getting an error that says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:25)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String rerun;
        do {
            System.out.println("What is your name?");
            String name = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("How many courses do you have?");
            int numCourse = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            String[][] timetable = new String[numCourse][2];
            for (int j = 0; j < numCourse; j++) {
                System.out.println("What is the name of your course #" + (j + 1) + "?");
                String course = input.nextLine();
                timetable[j][0] = course;
                System.out.println("What is your teachers name for " + course + "?");
                String teacher = input.nextLine();
                timetable[j][1] = teacher;
            }
            System.out.println("Hello " + name + ", here is your timetable:");
            for (int i = 0; i <= numCourse; i++) {
                System.out.format("\n%-30s%-30s", "Course #" + (i+1) + ": " + timetable[i][0],"Teacher: " + timetable[i][1]);
            }
            System.out.println("Would anyone else like to print their schedule? (yes/no)");
            rerun = input.next();
        }while(rerun.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample input which triggers your observation.

Comment: Does it cleanly run once? I.e. does it work if you remove the loop?

Comment: With and without the loop, it will run once, outputting my courses and teachers, but I get the same error I mentioned in my post after it runs once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in second for loop where you display your from array. put `next()` inplace of `nextLine()` because sometimes it skip the position.

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numCourse; i++) {
      System.out.format("\n%-30s%-30s", "Course #" + (i+1) + ": " + timetable[i][0],"Teacher: " + timetable[i][1]);
}
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < numCourse; i++) {
      System.out.format("\n%-30s%-30s", "Course #" + (i+1) + ": " + timetable[i][0],"Teacher: " + timetable[i][1]);
}
```

Suppose your `numCorse` is `2`. In your code, loop start from `0` and terminate after 2 so, Your loop working right while `i` is `0` and `1` but if `i` is going to `3` you get exception *ArrayIndexOutOfBound*.